# Laravel locale translate paragraph

Tags: laravel, localization, translation

I'd like to ask if this is the correct  way to translate a story:
`'story' => 'This is a story about <br> peanut butter. <br> Peanut butter tastes good.'`

Should I use `<br>` tags like above or is there another way?

Thanks,
g3

Answer (score 1):

You could make "story" an array.

For example:

```
'story' => [
   'This is a story about',
   'peanut butter',
   'Penut butter tastes good'
];
```

Then in your code:

```
@foreach($story as $paragraph)
   {{ $paragraph }}<br>
@endforeach
```

This way also supports unlimited paragraphs, which can be an issue across translation barriers.

Comment: Problem: can't use trans('cards.story') as argument for @foreach

Comment: See below for implemented solution using "trans('...')".

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented in my website.

```
@foreach (trans('menus.benefits_menu') as $key => $translation)
    <a href="{{ route('benefits', ['slug' => $key]) }}" class="{{ ($key == $uri) ? 'active' : ''}}">
        <div class="name">{{ $translation }}</div>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

You can see it working here: http://www.metinet.co/benefits/cloud_technology

(as the left hand menu)

Comment: What languages are supported? Also: Could you please change the text color, it's white on white o.o. Apart from that, website looks great man! :D